# How to make Grid fill the window?

Tags: wpf, grid

Now I have a Grid defined as follows,

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Grid1">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" Content="123"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Grid2" Visibility="Visible">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`Grid1` and `Grid2` have the same height.

[image]

When I set the Visibility of Grid2 to `Collapsed`, a blank area will be displayed under the Label.
[image]

How to remove this blank area?

It should be:

[image]

Comment: use Visibility="Hidden"

Comment: @MeysamAsadi not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Visibility` feature of the `Grid2` element to the height of the third row using `DataTrigger`.

```
<Grid Background="Red">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    <RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="*" />
             <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility,ElementName=Grid2}" Value="Hidden">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />        
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </RowDefinition.Style>
    </RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Grid1">
    <ListBox>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
  <Label Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" Content="123" />
  <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Grid2" Visibility="Hidden">
    <ListBox>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. This is indeed a workaround. But I would prefer an MVVM way to achieve it.